# Loop through array of variable names in Less

Tags: loops, less

In our app, we have a preset list of colors that a user can be choose from and everything related to that user will have that color.

Throughout the app, we will have various modules with the color attached as a class name.

eg.

```
<div class="example_module green">
  ...
</div>
```

We are using LESS for our CSS.

In a number of places we are doing things like this:

```
.example_module.green { background: @green; }
.example_module.red { background: @red; }
.example_module.blue { background: @blue; }
etc
```

I'd like to be able to set all these color names as an array and iterate over them. If we add colors in the future, we only have to add it in one place.

**Pseudo code:**

```
@colors: ['green', 'red', 'blue'];

for each @color in @colors {
  .example_module.@color { background: @color; }
}
```

Is something like this even supported in LESS?

Comment: It's possible in LESS using recursion. It's much more straightforward in SASS. Maybe you've heard of Google? ;^)

Comment: SASS is not the way to go. I understand why it seems easier to do, but in the long run LESS or a LESS fork will when out purely on syntax adherence.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

See [Loops](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature).
For example (assuming `@green`, `@red`, `@blue` variables are defined elsewhere):

```css
@colors: green, red, blue;

.example_module {
    .-(@i: length(@colors)) when (@i > 0) {
        @name: extract(@colors, @i);
        &.@{name} {background: @@name}
        .-((@i - 1));
    } .-;
}
```

### - - -

In Modern Less the same can be more straight-forward with the help of the [Lists](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists#less-plugin-lists) plugin:

```css
@colors: green, red, blue;

.for-each(@name in @colors) {
    .example_module.@{name} {
        background: @@name;
    }
}
```

### - - -

And in Legacy Less the syntactic sugar can be achieved using:

```css
@import "for";

@colors: green, red, blue;

.example_module {
    .for(@colors); .-each(@name) {
        &.@{name} {background: @@name}
    }
}
```

Where the imported `"for"` snippet (it's just a wrapper mixin for recursive Less loops) can be found [here](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/src/for.less) (with examples [here](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/articles/generic-for.md) and [here](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/articles/for-each.md)).

Comment: SyntaxError: Operation on an invalid type in common.less on line 6, column 3: 
```5 .example_module {
6   .for(@colors); .-each(@color) {
7   @name: e(@color);
```
by lessc 1.7.5

Comment: @seyed I'm afraid you need to create a new Q with complete example (this `for` thing is known to work fine in Less 1.5.x-2.0.x).

Comment: @seyed I was having that problem too. Mine was caused by a problem with the rhino-less integration; conflicting versions between the js.jar and less-rhino.x.x.x.js script.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to use 2 for loops inside the same less file without having mixed classes generated?

I mean, I have an array with colors and I generate background-colors rules and I want to generate my h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 rules using a for too, but the problem is that less is also generating mixed classes that don't have any sense, taking both arrays and applying both for loops.

Comment: @Fab See https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/blob/master/articles/generic-for.md#multiple-loops-in-same-scope

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks a lot, it worked.

Can you explain me why? what does it mean the & {} wrapper and the .-() {} wrapper?

Comment: @Fab `& {}` is just an "unnamed namespace" (see [Parent Selectors](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature)) and `.-() {}` is just an ordinary mixin named `.-`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks for clarification. Do you know if it is possible to use functions like lighten and darken inside a for loop?

Do you have any example?

Comment: @Fab Anything of Less can be used inside the loop - there's nothing special about it. (`.-each` is just an ordinary Less mixin so you can put whatever you need there). You'll find more example [here](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/public/).

Comment: @seven-phases-max this does not work with Less 2.6.1. Any idea why?

Comment: @Morgan I did not face any problems with 2.6.1 so I assume you need to create a new ticket (as the problem is elsewhere).

Comment: Hi @seven-phases-max please see this question I just posted for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352716/passing-a-variable-list-through-for-loop-using-less-2-6-1-is-unable-to-compile

Comment: 'for.less' wasn't found

What to do?

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor  Well, counting the link to the `for.less` *is* in the answer you probably need to read some beginners tutorial on what are CSS/Less imports and how to use them.

Answer (score 17):

[This mixin](https://github.com/kolosovsky/kolos.mixins/blob/master/for.less/) works fine for me. The second param is a code block that have access to the current iteration elem (@value) and index (@i).

1. Define mixin:

   ```
   .for(@list, @code) {
       & {
           .loop(@i:1) when (@i =< length(@list)) {
               @value: extract(@list, @i);

               @code();

               .loop(@i + 1);
           }

           .loop();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use:

   ```
   @colors: #1abc9c, #2ecc71, #3498db, #9b59b6;

   .for(@colors, {
       .color-@{i} {
           color: @value;
       }
   });
   ```
3. Result css:

   ```
   .color-1 {
     color: #1abc9c;
   }
   .color-2 {
     color: #2ecc71;
   }
   .color-3 {
     color: #3498db;
   }
   .color-4 {
     color: #9b59b6;
   }
   ```

Comment: Downvoting since it's not the answer to the question. You'd either need to modify your example to match the Q or find a more apropriate Q for your mixin library example (there're a lot of earlier and more general "how-to-loop" questions).

Comment: Also note though that DR based `.for-each` implementations were made since the day the DR-feature was added to Less, i.e. since 2014-02-27. And answering an old question just to post a link to yet another mixin library implementing something might not always be a good idea. (For your reference: [`1`](http://www.pnml.kz/2014/06/), [`2`](https://github.com/pixelass/homeless) etc. And finally see [#2270](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2270) for the summary of all possible sugar tricks by now).

Answer (score 14):

With modern LESS (>= 3.7), you can use the built-in [`each`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-each) function:

```css
/* (assuming @clr-green, @clr-red, @clr-blue variables are defined elsewhere) */
@colors: {
  green: @clr-green;
  red: @clr-red;
  blue: @clr-blue;
}

each(@colors, {
  .example_module.@{key} {
    background: @value;
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer, adding @index resolve my issue. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the ability to pass an object into each() in the latest documentation. Has this been deprecated?

Comment: @DanaWoodman No. It's right there in the docs. Second example.

Comment: *facepalm* yeah I see it now, not sure how I missed it. Ignore me ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Define mixin:

```css
.foreach(@list, @body, @i: length(@list)) when (@i>0) 
{
    .foreach(@list, @body, @i - 1);

    @n: length(@list);
    @value: extract(@list, @i);
    @body();
    /* you can use @value, @i, @n in the body */
}
```

2. Usage:

```css
.example-module {
  .foreach (red green blue,
  {
    &.@{value} {
      color: @value;
    }
  });
}
```

Another example:

```css
.nth-child (@list, @style) {
    .foreach(@list, 
    {
      @formula: e(%("%dn+%d", @n, @i));
      &:nth-child(@{formula}) {
        @style();
      }
    });
}

tr {
  .nth-child (#bbb #ccc #ddd #eee,
  {
      background: @value;
  });
}
```