# CSS3 changing background colors

Tags: css, background-color

I want to have a series of elements, and I want to have incremental background colors, but I also want to not hard-code it in order to allow for future expansion.

```
<div class="container">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
</div>
```

I could do something like this:

```
.container div:nth-child(0) {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
.container div:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #000066;
}
.container div:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

I would rather do that with a single rule, which would allow more succinct code and also allow for more extensibility (for, say, 6 elements). Is this even possible? I am aware that something like this is pretty straightforward with JQuery, but I would rather just use CSS if possible.

Comment: I would recommend using a CSS preprocessor like SASS or LESS. This works ideally for such use-cases ;)

Comment: While this doesn't directly solve your problem, you could achieve what you are talking about using a preprocessor like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) by using a loop. Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440789/loop-through-array-of-values-in-less.

Comment: I've heard of LESS, although I've never used it. I'll make sure to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can somehow handle this using a gradient, with a very big size, and setting just the position

```css
.container div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, blue);
  background-size: 20000px 20000px;
  }

.container div:nth-child(1) {
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}

.container div:nth-child(2) {
  background-position: 0% 30%;
}

.container div:nth-child(3) {
  background-position: 0% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting concept. Is this universally supported? On my browser (Firefox), all 3 boxes look the same.

Comment: There was a mistake that afected FF. Corrected !