# Passing a variable list through .for loop using Less 2.6.1 is unable to compile

Tags: less

I have been using a Less mixin which makes looping in Less, less verbose and is really handy: https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less.curious/

I upgraded from Less 2.6.0 to Less 2.6.1 and now the Less will not compile.

**Here's the Less code:**

```
// ............................................................
// .for

.for(@i, @n) {.-each(@i)}
.for(@n)     when (isnumber(@n)) {.for(1, @n)}
.for(@i, @n) when not (@i = @n)  {
.for((@i + (@n - @i) / abs(@n - @i)), @n);
}

// ............................................................
// .for-each

.for(@array)   when (default()) {.for-impl_(length(@array))}
.for-impl_(@i) when (@i > 1)    {.for-impl_((@i - 1))}
.for-impl_(@i) when (@i > 0)    {.-each(extract(@array, @i))}

@gray-base: #000;
@gray-darker: #222;
@gray-dark: #333;
@gray: #555;
@gray-light: #777;
@gray-lighter: #eee;

@gray-type:
 gray,
 gray-base,
 gray-dark,
 gray-darker,
 gray-light,
 gray-lighter;

.gray-type {
    // Mixin to generate the gray font colours for p tags in the font stacks.
    .for(@gray-type); .-each(@name) {
        .@{name} {
            color: @@name;
        }
    }   
}
```

**Here's the expected output:**

```
.gray-type .gray {
  color: #555;
}
.gray-type .gray-base {
  color: #000;
}
.gray-type .gray-dark {
  color: #333;
}
.gray-type .gray-darker {
  color: #222;
}
.gray-type .gray-light {
  color: #777;
}
.gray-type .gray-lighter {
  color: #eee;
}
```

**After upgrading to Less 2.6.1 I get the following error:**

```
>> SyntaxError: variable @[object Object],[object Object] is undefined in less/style.less on line 41, column 3:
>> 40       // Mixin to generate the gray font colours for p tags in the font stacks.
>> 41       .for(@gray-type); .-each(@name) {
>> 42           .@{name} {
Warning: Error compiling less/style.less Use --force to continue.
```

I think the problem is related to the hyphens being stripped from the variables during compilation, therefore making the variables passed though the list invalid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose this is this bug: [#2841](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2841). I thinks it's already fixed in the current master but the release was delayed for some reason. Meanwhile I guess it's better to use earlier versions (2.5.x), 2.6.x have a few critical bugs yet.

Comment: Aah ok, I was looking for a bug but didn't really know what to search for. Many thanks for explaining.

Comment: I have been encountering this same issue, You are correct in that the hyphens are the issue. If you can help it, changing your color names to NOT include hyphens does fix the problem

Comment: I would stick to the advice given by @seven-phases-max and use an older version of Less, then wait for the bug to be fixed before upgrading.