# Loop for generating data attributes/properties from variables in LESS

Tags: css, less

So, I've got a LESS file of color variables:

```
@colorNameOne: #ff5722;
@colorNameTwo: #ff5722;
@colorNameThree: orange;
```

I want to go through each color in this list and generate something to this effect

**Psuedo Code**

```
for each color:

div[data-color="n"] {
    background-color: @colorName
}
```

where `n` is the number of the color you're on. (i.e. `n` for `@colorNameTwo` is 2)

Tried a few things but I'm new to LESS loops so any advice on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through array of variable names in Less](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440789/loop-through-array-of-variable-names-in-less)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: @SergChernata I'm trying to avoid writing each color name out manually, but this is still a useful link for other reasons

Comment: "I'm trying to avoid writing each color name out manually" than you just declare these colors as an array and not individual variables. (In a real project a list of global variables cannot serve as some useful data array since it will contain everything you've got in the project and not just colors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store colornames in array ,not separate variables for each color.

After that you can just loop over it with index in order you want

Comment: Are you certain this is the only way this can be achieved? I'm trying to avoid re-structuring a rather large color library.

Comment: If you want to keep color variables just store their names in another array :with direct reference to ((div[data-color="n"] )) n variable.
it would be the same as this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440789/loop-through-array-of-variable-names-in-less